# Retrieve IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I have Visual Studio 2017 installed on Windows 10 64 bit.  It was all working fine but something has happened to IIS Express 10.  Now if I try creating an ASP.NET web project it states Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)).  IIS Express no longer appears to be in the list of programs but the folders are in the "Program Files" location.  I tried downloading IIS Express but it is a x86 version and will not install.

How do I retrieve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user Lex Li who alerted me to the fact that IIS 8 will not work with Visual Studio 2017 I investigated this again.  The link Lex Li provided (https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=48264) had download options for 64 bit but I was unsure about these because they initially appear to be for machines running AMD processors but I found the additional links below that advises that AMD were the first to develop a 64 bit version and Microsoft simply uses this.  I downloaded and installed the 64 bit and appears to work okay with VS2017 so far

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-files/why-are-there-amd64-files-on-an-intel-machine/7482ee8f-511a-45c0-b3a3-8542a74801c9?db=5

https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/what-the-heck-is-amd64/

Answer (score 0):

Found a version 8 of IIS Express called iisexpress_8_0_RTM_x64_en-US.msi which allowed me to install over and appears to run okay

Comment: But you need to install IIS 10 Express https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=48264. IIS 8 Express is not compatible with VS2017.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the link.  I spent some time trying to find this.  I have downloaded and will remove IIS 8 Express and install IIS 10 Express